# Part of DROOLS ruleflow not working randomly

Tags: drools, rule-engine

We have a main ruleflow which calls 8 more rule flows (Rule1.rf to Rule8.rf) through an AND splitter. One of the rule flows - say Rules4.rf - is fired sometimes and not fired sometimes.

This is for an online application and we use jBoss. When the server is started, everything works fine. After many hours, for some requests, Rules4.rf is not fired at all and for others, its fired properly.

We even posted the same request again and again and the issue happens some times only. There is no difference in the logs between the success & failure requests, except for the logs from the Rules4.rf which missing in failued requests.

We are using drools 5.1 and java 6.
Please help me. This is creating a very big issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is very difficult to figure out what might be going on without being able to look at the actual code and log.  Could you by any chance create a JIRA and attach the process and if possible (a part of) an audit log that shows the issue?

Kris